# How to execute fetch paths without interfering with webpage pathname?

Tags: javascript, django, fetch, url-pattern

I am working on a Django project and got stuck on url patterns and routes.

On `index.html`, the pathname is `""` and the JS functions are working great. The fetch url `tweets/${tweetid}` is matching with Django API route url pattern `tweets/<int:tweetid>` and is working fine.

However, on `profile.html`, the pathname is `"profile/<int:userid>"` and JS is not working here. The fetch url `tweets/${tweetid}` results the final path `profile/tweets/<int:tweetid>`. Since that is not in `urls.py`, I am getting an error.

How can I execute my fetch and JS functions on any html page in this web application?

Answer (score 0):

You should start the path with a leading slash (`/`) to use an *absolute* path, not a *relative* path, so:

```
/tweets/${tweetid}
```

The leading slash means that it will for example fetch the page `hostname.ext/tweets/1234`. If you use a relative path (without a leading slash), the item will be appended to the already specified path.